# Reorganizing sparse pandas dataframe in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this :

| Index | col1 | col2 | col3 | key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | str1 | None | None | A |
| 2 | str2 | str3 | None | A |
| 3 | str4 | str5 | str6 | B |
| 4 | str7 | None | None | B |

I'd like to have all the values in col1-col2-col3 in one column, while keeping the associated key, like this :

| Index | colnew | key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | str1 | A |
| 2 | str2 | A |
| 3 | str3 | A |
| 4 | str4 | B |
| 5 | str5 | B |
| 6 | str6 | B |
| 7 | str7 | B |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via melt:

```
df=(df.melt('key',value_name='colnew')
      .dropna(subset=['colnew'])
      .drop('variable',1)
      .sort_values('colnew'))
```